# Guitars hum consistently, even while touching strings

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, noise, solid-body-electric-guitars, ibanez

Ibanez Gio GRG220PA and Fender Starcaster constantly hum when plugged into either my amp or audio interface. The hum doesn't get better or worse when I touch the strings, unlike what's often reported by other people with their guitars. I note the following:

- The hum/noise sounds **exactly the same** with either guitar.
- There is no noise when only the amp or interface + monitors is on without the guitars connected.
- I bought a multimeter and tested the ground continuity in the Gio since it's the newer guitar. All seems fine there. I also tested the
  ground connection in the electrical outlet itself, again with no
  issues.
- I have worked around this issue for months by cutting the noisy frequencies with eq, but that makes my tone sound undesirably muffled

I'm pretty new to both playing guitar and electrical work, so I'm not sure if there's something I'm overlooking. I don't know what to try next. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried moving to another room? Sometimes the hum comes from the lighting or other electrical devices in the room and is picked up by the guitars and the only options are either disabling those devices or moving away from them.

Comment: I have tried different rooms, but no luck

Comment: Different cable?

Comment: Tried a Hosa right angle and Fender straight cable. Noise is exactly the same on both, and they're both pretty new cables

Comment: Do you have a laptop you can run on battery only, to eliminate mains as the issue? Can you get a tuner in-line & tell us what note it is? 50Hz mains registers just sharp of G, 60Hz just flat of B. Also, rather than testing by touching the strings, use a metal-cased jack & touch the case with a damp finger.

Comment: Okay I feel a bit silly. Apparently the noise was being caused by my laptop which is what I use to record. So when I went to different rooms, I was bringing the noise around with me. Trying the different rooms with the amp alone, I get almost no noise, but only when I face particular directions. My guitar cables are pretty long so I tried standing on the other side of the room and facing different directions while connected to the interface and laptop (no luck). So how do I record when my laptop is the main source of the noise? Should I create a new thread for this?

Comment: As per my previous comment - did you try it running only on battery?

Comment: @Tetsujin I just tried battery only. It made some of the hiss at 6khz go away, but the bulk of the noise at 4khz is still there. When I turn my body nearly 180 degrees to the right, that gets rid of a decent amount of the 4khz noise whether the laptop is plugged in or not, but it's still audible. Using SPAN plugin for the frequency readings.

Comment: Ahhh, right. When you said 'hum' I [like I would guess everybody else] assumed you meant down in the 50 - 150Hz range. Up at 4 - 6kHz you've got 'something' in the laptop's electronics emitting EMI/RFI. Finding what that 'something' is is not going to be easy. (It's times like this I'm glad I have a Variax - simply not subject to EMI at all;)

Comment: I did some searching and stumbled upon the Bertom Denoiser plug in. It seems to be doing a good job cutting the noise without noticeably affecting my tone, so I'll stick with it. Thanks for your time, everyone!

Comment: Does your audio interface include USB connection? I've seen some that, when connected to the PC, transmit all inputs through that port and it seems more frequency-controlled (maybe more artifitius-sounded but getting that USB advantage) so maybe that helps you eliminate the hum instead of running another software at the same time.